# Ubuntu freezes after hardware reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

I've come across a strange enough problem in the past days that I need to write my question down here.

I have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu on one NVME and Windows on the other. The Bootmanager is installed on the Ubuntu drive so I always start that first and then go to Windows from there. The Ubuntu system is used for work while I use Windows primarily for Hobbies and Gaming.

The whole system (CPU+GPU) is water-cooled.

I had the problem of Ubuntu freezing roughly once a day for a few weeks or even months now but it didn't really bother me enough to do something about it.

A few days ago, after taking everything apart, cleaning the water-cooling loop and putting all the hardware back together the freezing appeared way more frequently. I can't really keep the system running for more than an hour without it freezing completely up. And it's completely frozen then, programs stop, the cursor stops and even the clock stops going. Sometimes I can still hear people talking over Zoom for some more time.

- I tried reseating the RAM and changing the slots so far but that did not make a difference.
- I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu once which also did not make much of a difference.
- I then thought there was an issue with the graphics card maybe and I took that one apart again this afternoon to retighten all the screws and make sure that I applied the correct amount of thermal paste which I seem to have.

After about 50 minutes of the system running a complete freeze occurred again.

All of this would indicate some sort of hardware issue with the GPU to me, but there does not seem to be any issue when running Windows. I played some games over the weekend for multiple hours nonstop (some of which are quite demanding) but no issue occurred.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can fix that issue or even possibly find out what the problem is? I wasn't able to find any logs which could tell me what the problem is but I am also not too experienced with reading them so that could just be on me

##### Additional information:

All the components are running on the stock clocks and I did not do any overclocking. RAM was tested with XMP on and off.
The GPU is staying below 50°C and the CPU is staying between 60°C and 70°C.
Both components get hotter while gaming but there are no crashes or freezes while doing so

##### Used drivers:

I have so far tried `nvidia-driver-525`, `nvidia-driver-520` and `nvidia-driver-510` which all lead to freezes.

Sometimes the whole PC freezes at once but some other times only applications are affected first (not being able to add more text input) before the clock and cursor freezes eventually.

Comment: Are you overclocking (CPU,GPU,Ram,FSB)? If so, reset to defaults and start from there. 
Run [memtest](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=memtest86) over night and 
monitor temperature/fans when you are working. Try a different graphic card or driver to rule out this component.

Comment: Everything is on stock and I also tried turning on/off the XMP profile for the RAM already.
I've had a look at the temperatures already and the graphics cards stays below 50°C while the CPU is is bit hotter between 60°C and 70°C. I'll add that information to the main post as well

Comment: My first guess would be a problem with the graphics driver. Check if you can get an updated driver / firmware update.

Comment: Indeed ^^^ . Most newer Nvidias will randomly freeze without the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: I originally had nvidia-driver-520, I then updated to 525, downgraded to 515 and now also  downgraded to 460 again. I experienced the crashes with 525, 520 and 515 so far. Can't tell about 460 as I just switched to that now

I also did a firmware update for the graphics card yesterday which did not make a difference.

I will try switching to my old GTX 760 this afternoon if the problem persists with the even older driver as well now

Comment: Update: Driver 460 also crashes, so no change there

It also seems like the freeze exclusively occurs when I am using zoom

Comment: I swapped to my old GTX 760 just for the system to freeze again after around an hour. I guess in that case it's not the graphics card then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resolved the problem by replacing Motherboard CPU and RAM.
RAM was most likely not the issue but I wasn't able to test the Motherboard and CPU individually and the new board had DDR5 now.